# Javascript automatic prompt choice

Tags: javascript

This is a code from the prompt which appears when trying to send an e-mail to specific people, and I wonder if it's possible to make "Continue anyway" run automatically when this prompt is opened without having to click it. Been trying to achieve it myself, but my Javascript knowledge doesn't allow me to do it.

Prompt example

[image]

I tried creating a javascript code that would be implemented in Violentmonkey, but I can't find a way to do it..

So this part of the code is responsible for "continue anyway" part, but I can't come up with a way to make it so that it's automatically pressed

```
ya.jsx)(Kn, {
  onClick: $,
  "data-testid": eI,
  children: re.formatMessage({
    id: "i18n.tco.ng.priceproposals.DIALOG_COMMUNICATION_SUBMIT"
  })
```

```js
JC = "PriceProposalContactConfirmDialog/createPPLButton", eI = "PriceProposalContactConfirmDialog/confirmButton", tI = "PriceProposalContactConfirmDialog/abortButton", PriceProposalContactConfirmDialog = V => {
  let {
    onConfirm: $,
    onClose: Z,
    onClickOpenPriceProposalDialog: ee,
    showCreatePriceProposalButton: te
  } = V;
  const re = useIntl(),
    onClickCreatePriceProposal = () => {
      Z(),
        ee()
    };
  return (0,
    ya.jsx)(ConfirmDialog, {
    headline: re.formatMessage({
      id: "i18n.tco.ng.priceproposals.DIALOG_COMMUNICATION_HEADER"
    }),
    message: (0,
      ya.jsx)("div", {
      children: re.formatMessage({
        id: "i18n.tco.ng.priceproposals.DIALOG_COMMUNICATION_INFO"
      })
    }),
    onClose: Z,
    customFooter: te ? (0,
      ya.jsxs)(ya.Fragment, {
      children: [(0,
        ya.jsx)(Kn, {
        buttonStyle: "primary",
        autoFocus: !0,
        onClick: onClickCreatePriceProposal,
        "data-testid": JC,
        children: re.formatMessage({
          id: "i18n.tco.ng.priceproposals.SUBMIT_DIALOG_HEADER"
        })
      }), (0,
        ya.jsx)(Kn, {
        onClick: $,
        "data-testid": eI,
        children: re.formatMessage({
          id: "i18n.tco.ng.priceproposals.DIALOG_COMMUNICATION_SUBMIT"
        })
      }), (0,
        ya.jsx)(Kn, {
        onClick: Z,
        buttonStyle: "text",
        "data-testid": tI,
        children: re.formatMessage({
          id: "i18n.tco.ng.ABORT"
        })
      })]
    }) : (0,
      ya.jsxs)(ya.Fragment, {
      children: [(0,
        ya.jsx)(Kn, { **
        onClick: $,
        buttonStyle: "primary",
        autoFocus: !0,
        "data-testid": eI,
        children: re.formatMessage({ **
          id: "i18n.tco.ng.priceproposals.DIALOG_COMMUNICATION_SUBMIT"
        })
      }), (0,
        ya.jsx)(Kn, {
        onClick: Z,
        buttonStyle: "text",
        "data-testid": tI,
        children: re.formatMessage({
          id: "i18n.tco.ng.ABORT"
        })
      })]
    })
  })
}
```

If I understand it correctly, button ID for "Continue anyway" is this: "Normalize_normalize__5biS5.Button_button__PnIym"
[image: Button ID]

So I tried creating something myself, but it doesn't work..

```
(function() {
'use strict';

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = '';
});

window.alert = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
};

window.prompt = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    return true;
};

window.confirm = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    var continueAnywayButton = document.querySelector('Normalize_normalize__5biS5.Button_button__PnIym');
    if (continueAnywayButton) {
        continueAnywayButton.click();
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

})();

Comment: Is `Normalize_normalize__5biS5.Button_button__PnIym` the id of the element? If so you would need to change it to `#Normalize_normalize__5biS5.Button_button__PnIym`. querySelector works with css selectors so without the `#` it looks for the element instead of the id.

Comment: What causes the prompt to show? (you may be able to stop the prompt showing and directly call the continue anyway code) Also, in your screenshot there is an element with a `no-js` class above your prompt, what is inside it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comments, I came up with a way to detect a text shown when the prompt appears, and if the text is present, the "continue anyway" option is then selected.

[image: code]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)